# C++ programming average score program

Tags: c++, arrays

The program below basically asks the user for their average grade (as a % out of 100) for each of the grade categories. If there is no data for a category, the user should enter the value -1. In such cases, the total score used to calculate our average changes. After all categories have had information input, the user’s class grade is calculated based on the syllabus values in the picture link. Display a percentage and letter grade to the user.

**I am stuck on the part where the user does not enter data for a category and the user is supposed to enter -1 which means the total score used to calculate the average changes. What should I do to meet this requirement**

[Image of categories and score](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2moo1.png)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int marks[5], i;
    float sum=0,avg;

    cout<<"\n Enter Marks of Student \n";
    cout<<"------------------------------------";
    cout<<"\n Quizzes : ";
    cin>>marks[0];
    cout<<"\n Labwork : ";
    cin>>marks[1];
    cout<<"\n Midterm : ";
    cin>>marks[2];
    cout<<"\n Final : ";
    cin>>marks[3];
    cout<<"\n Participation : ";
    cin>>marks[4];

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
            sum=sum+marks[i];
    }
    cout<<"------------------------------------";
    cout<<"\n Total Marks of Student = "<<sum;
    cout<<"\n Grade   = ";

    if(sum>80)
    {
            cout<<"A";
    }
    else if(sum>60 && sum<=80)
    {
            cout<<"B";
    }
    else if(sum>40 && sum<=60)
    {
            cout<<"C";
    }
    else
    {
            cout<<"D";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am stuck on the part where the user does not enter data for a category and the user is supposed to enter -1 which means the total score used to calculate the average changes. What should I do to meet this requirement

1. You have to make sure that you don't add `marks[i]` to `sum` if `marks[i]` is equal to -1.
2. You have to keep count of how may valid marks were entered. This will be necessary to compute the average.
3. You are not computing average anywhere in your code. Divide `sum` by the number of valid marks to get the average.
4. Use the average to compute the final grade.

---

```
int validCounter = 0;
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
   if ( marks[i] != -1 )
   {
      sum=sum+marks[i];
      ++validCounter;
   }
}

int average = 0;
if ( validCounter == 0 )
{
   // Failed from lack of attendance, maybe
}
else
{
   average = sum/validCounter;
}
```

Comment: // Failed from lack of attendance, maybe.....comments are fun sometimes :D

Comment: @kiranBiradar, that's one outlet for us to add some humor to our job.